# Confluent Schema Registry on Strimzi - pods not getting created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, confluent-schema-registry, strimzi, k8s-serviceaccount

I've Strimzi Kafka installed on GKE(GCP), and i'm trying to install Confluent Schema registry referring link -

```
https://github.com/lsst-sqre/strimzi-registry-operator
```

Steps followed:

1. Installed strimzi-registry-operator in namespace schema-registry-operator,
   Note : Strimzi Kafka is installed in namespace - kafka

Command used :

```
helm repo add lsstsqre https://lsst-sqre.github.io/charts/
helm repo update
helm install ssr lsstsqre/strimzi-registry-operator -n schema-registry-operator --values values.yaml

values.yaml:
------------
# -- Name of the Strimzi Kafka cluster
clusterName: "versa-kafka-gke"

# -- Namespace where the Strimzi Kafka cluster is deployed
clusterNamespace: "kafka"

# -- Namespace where the strimzi-registry-operator is deployed
operatorNamespace: "strimzi-registry-operator"
```

Step 2:
Installed the kafkatopic (registry-schemas),kafkauser in schema - 'kafka'
(Note : Strimzi kafka is also installed in the namespace - kafka)

```
kafkatopic.yaml
----------------
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaTopic
metadata:
  name: registry-schemas
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: versa-kafka-gke
spec:
  partitions: 1
  replicas: 3
  config:
    # http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs
    cleanup.policy: compact


kafkauser.yaml
--------------

apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaUser
metadata:
  name: confluent-schema-registry
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: versa-kafka-gke
spec:
  authentication:
    type: tls
  authorization:
    # Official docs on authorizations required for the Schema Registry:
    # https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/security/index.html#authorizing-access-to-the-schemas-topic
    type: simple
    acls:
      # Allow all operations on the registry-schemas topic
      # Read, Write, and DescribeConfigs are known to be required
      - resource:
          type: topic
          name: registry-schemas
          patternType: literal
        operation: All
        type: allow
      # Allow all operations on the schema-registry* group
      - resource:
          type: group
          name: schema-registry
          patternType: prefix
        operation: All
        type: allow
      # Allow Describe on the __consumer_offsets topic
      - resource:
          type: topic
          name: __consumer_offsets
          patternType: literal
        operation: Describe
        type: allow
```

Step3 :
Installed StrimziSchemaRegistry in schema - strimzi-schema-operator

Here is what i see in the schema svchema-registry-operator:

```
(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:schema-registry-yamls karanalang$ kc get all -n schema-registry-operator
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/strimzi-registry-operator-7867fbc985-rddqw   1/1     Running   0          121m

NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/strimzi-registry-operator   1/1     1            1           121m

NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/strimzi-registry-operator-7867fbc985   1         1         1       121m
```

Also, when i logon to the SchemaRegistryOperator pod, i see the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/aiokits/aiotasks.py", line 108, in guard
    await coro
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_core/reactor/queueing.py", line 175, in watcher
    async for raw_event in stream:
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/watching.py", line 82, in infinite_watch
    async for raw_event in stream:
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/watching.py", line 159, in continuous_watch
    objs, resource_version = await fetching.list_objs(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/fetching.py", line 28, in list_objs
    rsp = await api.get(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/api.py", line 111, in get
    response = await request(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/auth.py", line 45, in wrapper
    return await fn(*args, **kwargs, context=context)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/api.py", line 85, in request
    await errors.check_response(response)  # but do not parse it!
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/errors.py", line 150, in check_response
    raise cls(payload, status=response.status) from e
kopf._cogs.clients.errors.APIForbiddenError: ('secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:schema-registry-operator:strimzi-registry-operator" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "kafka"', {'kind': 'Status', 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'metadata': {}, 'status': 'Failure', 'message': 'secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:schema-registry-operator:strimzi-registry-operator" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "kafka"', 'reason': 'Forbidden', 'details': {'kind': 'secrets'}, 'code': 403})
[2022-11-30 23:27:39,605] kopf._cogs.clients.w [DEBUG   ] Stopping the watch-stream for strimzischemaregistries.v1beta1.roundtable.lsst.codes in 'kafka'.
[2022-11-30 23:27:39,606] kopf._core.reactor.o [ERROR   ] Watcher for strimzischemaregistries.v1beta1.roundtable.lsst.codes@kafka has failed: ('strimzischemaregistries.roundtable.lsst.codes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:schema-registry-operator:strimzi-registry-operator" cannot list resource "strimzischemaregistries" in API group "roundtable.lsst.codes" in the namespace "kafka"', {'kind': 'Status', 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'metadata': {}, 'status': 'Failure', 'message': 'strimzischemaregistries.roundtable.lsst.codes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:schema-registry-operator:strimzi-registry-operator" cannot list resource "strimzischemaregistries" in API group "roundtable.lsst.codes" in the namespace "kafka"', 'reason': 'Forbidden', 'details': {'group': 'roundtable.lsst.codes', 'kind': 'strimzischemaregistries'}, 'code': 403})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/errors.py", line 148, in check_response
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 1004, in raise_for_status
    raise ClientResponseError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 403, message='Forbidden', url=URL('https://10.44.0.1:443/apis/roundtable.lsst.codes/v1beta1/namespaces/kafka/strimzischemaregistries')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/aiokits/aiotasks.py", line 108, in guard
    await coro
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_core/reactor/queueing.py", line 175, in watcher
    async for raw_event in stream:
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/watching.py", line 82, in infinite_watch
    async for raw_event in stream:
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/watching.py", line 159, in continuous_watch
    objs, resource_version = await fetching.list_objs(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/fetching.py", line 28, in list_objs
    rsp = await api.get(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/api.py", line 111, in get
    response = await request(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/auth.py", line 45, in wrapper
    return await fn(*args, **kwargs, context=context)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/api.py", line 85, in request
    await errors.check_response(response)  # but do not parse it!
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_cogs/clients/errors.py", line 150, in check_response
    raise cls(payload, status=response.status) from e
kopf._cogs.clients.errors.APIForbiddenError: ('strimzischemaregistries.roundtable.lsst.codes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:schema-registry-operator:strimzi-registry-operator" cannot list resource "strimzischemaregistries" in API group "roundtable.lsst.codes" in the namespace "kafka"', {'kind': 'Status', 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'metadata': {}, 'status': 'Failure', 'message': 'strimzischemaregistries.roundtable.lsst.codes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:schema-registry-operator:strimzi-registry-operator" cannot list resource "strimzischemaregistries" in API group "roundtable.lsst.codes" in the namespace "kafka"', 'reason': 'Forbidden', 'details': {'group': 'roundtable.lsst.codes', 'kind': 'strimzischemaregistries'}, 'code': 403})
```

Few questions on this:

- I don't see the schemaRegistry pod getting created which would be listening on port 8081, only the StrimziSchemaRegistry object is created in schema - strimzi-schema-operator

How do i get access to the SchemaRegistry url so i can upload schemas to it ?

How do i resolve the permission error above ?
Do I need to create a separate service account for installinh schema-registry ?

Pls advise.

tia!

Update :
This is an existing issue with the Strimzi Schema Registry operator (https://github.com/lsst-sqre/strimzi-registry-operator/issues/79).
Essentially, the ServiceAccount is not created in the correct namespace, I re-created the ServiceAccount in namespace - strimzi-registry-operator to resolve the issue.

However, i'm facing another issue (existing issue - https://github.com/lsst-sqre/strimzi-registry-operator/issues/84), the schema registry is not getting created.

Additional Details :

Schema-Registry-operator is deployed in namespace - 'strimzi-registry-operator'
Strimzi Kafka(cluster - versa-kafka-gke) - deployed in namespace - 'kafka'

Part of the Strimzi kafka yaml, with version & listeners :

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: versa-kafka-gke #1
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.0.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: tls  
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: loadbalancer
        tls: true 
        authentication:
          type: tls
    authorization:
      type: simple    
KafkaUser (confluent-schema-registry) & KafkaTopic (registry-schemas), deployed in namespace - 'kafka'
Confluent Schema Registry - deployed in namespace - 'kafka' (
```

Error :

```
Events:
  Type   Reason   Age   From  Message
  ----   ------   ----  ----  -------
  Error  Logging  73s   kopf  Handler 'create_registry' failed with an exception. Will retry.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_core/actions/execution.py", line 279, in execute_handler_once
    result = await invoke_handler(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_core/actions/execution.py", line 374, in invoke_handler
    result = await invocation.invoke(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_core/actions/invocation.py", line 139, in invoke
    await asy...al/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/strimziregistryoperator/handlers/createregistry.py", line 131, in create_registry
    bootstrap_server = get_kafka_bootstrap_server(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/strimziregistryoperator/deployments.py", line 83, in get_kafka_bootstrap_server
    raise kopf.Error(msg, delay=10)
AttributeError: module 'kopf' has no attribute 'Error'
  Normal  Logging  73s  kopf  Creating a new Schema Registry deployment: confluent-schema-registry with listener=tls (security protocol=tls) and strimzi-version=v1beta2 serviceType=ClusterIP image=confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.2.1
  Normal  Logging  12s  kopf  Creating a new Schema Registry deployment: confluent-schema-registry with listener=tls (security protocol=tls) and strimzi-version=v1beta2 serviceType=ClusterIP image=confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.2.1
  Error   Logging  12s  kopf  Handler 'create_registry' failed with an exception. Will retry.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_core/actions/execution.py", line 279, in execute_handler_once
    result = await invoke_handler(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_core/actions/execution.py", line 374, in invoke_handler
    result = await invocation.invoke(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kopf/_core/actions/invocation.py", line 139, in invoke
    await asy...al/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/strimziregistryoperator/handlers/createregistry.py", line 131, in create_registry
    bootstrap_server = get_kafka_bootstrap_server(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/strimziregistryoperator/deployments.py", line 83, in get_kafka_bootstrap_server
    raise kopf.Error(msg, delay=10)
AttributeError: module 'kopf' has no attribute 'Error'
```

Comment: I know nothing abotu the registry operator ... but from the error, you did not correctly configured the RBAC resources and it is missing some rights.

Comment: @Jakub - yes, from the error - it seems the Strimzi Schema Registry operator requires ServiceAccount (strimzi-registry-operator), and a RoleBinding binds the  the service account to namespace strimzi-registry-operator, however - that is not mentioned in the readme .. infact, there is no RoleBinding created, but a ClusterRoleBinding is created instead; seems the Strimzi Schema Registry needs the readme updated ?

Comment: I saw you also asked in [GitHub](https://github.com/lsst-sqre/strimzi-registry-operator/issues/84#issuecomment-1341531910) and I met same error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76157971/2000548) is a solution using Confluent Schema Registry packaged by Bitnami. It works well with Kafka created by Strimzi too. 

Comment: how to expose schema registry external access with mtls?