# How to install Confluent Schema Registry using Bitnami helm chart for external Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, bitnami, confluent-schema-registry

I have a Kafka created by Strimzi at `hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092`.

I am trying to install Confluent Schema Registry using Bitnami helm at https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/schema-registry

Here are my steps:

```bash
helm upgrade \
  confluent-schema-registry \
  oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/schema-registry \
  --install \
  --namespace=hm-confluent-schema-registry \
  --create-namespace \
  --values=my-values.yaml
```

**my-values.yaml**:

```yaml
kafka:
  enabled: false
externalKafka:
  brokers:
    - PLAINTEXT://hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092
```

However, this gives me error

```bash
Error: template: schema-registry/templates/statefulset.yaml:4:95: executing "schema-registry/templates/statefulset.yaml" at <.Values.kafka.auth.clientProtocol>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.clientProtocol
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

Assume the Kafka is at `hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092`, Confluent Schema Registry can be installed by

```bash
helm upgrade \
  confluent-schema-registry \
  oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/schema-registry \
  --install \
  --namespace=hm-confluent-schema-registry \
  --create-namespace \
  --values=my-values.yaml
```

**my-values.yaml**:

```yaml
kafka:
  enabled: false
  auth:
    protocol: {}
  service:
    ports:
      client: {}
externalKafka:
  brokers:
    - PLAINTEXT://hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092
```

---

## How I found out

### Attempt 2 (Failed)

I did further experiments based on the error I got in my question, I updated to

**my-values.yaml**:

```yaml
kafka:
  enabled: false
  auth:
    protocol: plaintext
externalKafka:
  brokers:
    - PLAINTEXT://hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092
```

gives me error

```bash
Error: template: schema-registry/templates/statefulset.yaml:7:29: executing "schema-registry/templates/statefulset.yaml" at <.Values.kafka.service.ports.client>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.ports
```

### Attempt 3 (Succeed)

**my-values.yaml**:

```yaml
kafka:
  enabled: false
  auth:
    protocol: plaintext
  service:
    ports:
      client: 9092
externalKafka:
  brokers:
    - PLAINTEXT://hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092
```

Now I can see default `_schemas` from Confluent Schema Registry got created with some messages inside:

[image]

The issue is that these two parameters currently do not exist in [schema-registry/values.yaml](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/c693dd78f26da6c495a9566c6a5b49ba15c6587c/bitnami/schema-registry/values.yaml):

```yaml
kafka:
  auth:
    protocol: plaintext
  service:
    ports:
      client: 9092
```

I have reported the issue at https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/17126

---

## UPDATE

@wackazong pointed out can simply use

```yaml
kafka:
  enabled: false
  auth:
    protocol: {}
  service:
    ports:
      client: {}
externalKafka:
  brokers:
    - PLAINTEXT://hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092
```

Confirmed it works. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how can I add basic authentication and mTLS authentication to the schema registry?

Answer (score 0):

You can just supply some empty objects until the helm chart is fixed:

```
   kafka:
     enabled: false
     auth: {}
     service:
       ports: {}
   externalKafka:
     brokers:
       - PLAINTEXT://hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue with the latest schema-registry helm chart from Bitnami. Version 14.0.0 app version 7.4.1.                                                                                          I have above-mentioned setting in the values.yaml. The schema is blank. Nothing is shown in schema nor even the default schema.